# how to get the seletect row form listview and then Delete from Sqlite data base

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-studio

I am an new to Android. I have a problem when I select the multiple rows through checkbox it will delete the last row instead on 1st row, when I select the whole Listview it delete all the list correctly....
here is my Main Activity code

```
private void showDialog(final String warning, final String s) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    adb.setTitle(warning);

    adb.setMessage(s);
    adb.setIcon(R.drawable.deleteicon);

    String btn = "Ok";
    if (warning.equals("Warning")) {
        btn = "Yes";

        adb.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }

    adb.setPositiveButton(btn, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (warning.equals("Warning")) {
                int size = image_adapter.checkStatesArray.length;
                for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                    if (image_adapter.checkStatesArray[i] == true) {
                        db.deleteImage(i);
                    }
                    image_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                // listView.clearChoices();
                UpdateList();

                /*    sparseBooleanArray=listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
                for (int i=0;i<sparseBooleanArray.size();i++){
                    if (sparseBooleanArray.valueAt(i)) {
                        int key = (int) image_adapter.getItemId(i);
                        db.deleteImage(key);
                        //db.deleteImage(key);
                }*/
            }
        }
    });
    adb.show();
}
```

Here is Adapter class code. I assign the state of check box to a Boolean Array

```
 viewholder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int id=(Integer)buttonView.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(context, "clickd position"+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            images.get(id).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
            if (buttonView.isChecked()){
                checkStatesArray[id]=true;
            }
            else {
                checkStatesArray[id] = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

And Database Delete funcation. here

```
public void deleteImage(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=this.getAll();
    //database=this.getReadableDatabase();
    //database.delete(TABLE_NAME,"id="+id,null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    for (int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++){
        id=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME,"id="+id,null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in deleteImage Method,you are getting all the id's in for loop.there you will read all the elements and last one will be the id which you are deleting.
Change the code to following.

```
 public void deleteImage(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME,"id="+id,null);
}
```